# Generating indices based on a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am generating indices based on `N,V`. However, I am not getting the desired output. I present the current and expected output.

```
N = 3
V = [3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20]

# Ensure the length of H is a multiple of (N+1)
if len(V) % (N + 1) == 0:
    # Sort the list in ascending order (if needed)
    V.sort()

    # Calculate the number of subsets needed
    num_subsets = len(V) // (N + 1)

    for i in range(num_subsets):
        subset = V[i * (N + 1): (i + 1) * (N + 1)]
        print(f"Subset {i + 1}:", subset)

        # Assign indices for each element in the subset with the specified pattern
        indices_subset = [(j * 2 - 3 + i * (N + 1), -1 - i * (N + 1)) for j in range(1, N + 2)]
        print(f"Indices for Subset {i + 1}:", indices_subset)

else:
    print(f"The length of V ({len(V)}) is not a multiple of {N+1}. Cannot split into subsets.")
```

The current output is

```
Subset 1: [3, 4, 5, 6]
Indices for Subset 1: [(-1, -1), (1, -1), (3, -1), (5, -1)]
Subset 2: [10, 11, 12, 13]
Indices for Subset 2: [(3, -5), (5, -5), (7, -5), (9, -5)]
Subset 3: [17, 18, 19, 20]
Indices for Subset 3: [(7, -9), (9, -9), (11, -9), (13, -9)]
```

The expected output is

```
Subset 1: [3, 4, 5, 6]
Indices for Subset 1: [(-1, -1), (1, -1), (3, -1), (5, -1)]
Subset 2: [10, 11, 12, 13]
Indices for Subset 2: [(-1, -3), (1, -3), (3, -3), (5, -3)]
Subset 3: [17, 18, 19, 20]
Indices for Subset 3: [(-1, -5), (1, -5), (3, -5), (5, -5)]
```

Comment: What is the indices pattern? It's not obvious (to me) just from your expected output.

Comment: The x-coordinate of each starts with -1 with an increment of 2 and the y-coordinate is -1 for each subset and decreases by 2 for subsequent ones.

Comment: So in your code, x should only depend on j, and y should only depend on i, right?

Comment: x-increments by 2, starting from -1
y remains constant for one subset but increments by -2 for subsequent subsets.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Do you understand my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and the example you chose (list of len 12 with `N=3` which makes `12/3=4=N+1` => probably the reason why `N+1` appears in your code) are quite confusing. From your printed message `The length of V ({len(V)}) is not a multiple of {N+1}. Cannot split into subsets.` and your expected output, I guess you actually want to split `V` into `N` subsets:

```
N = 3
V = [3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20]

# Ensure the length of V is a multiple of N
if len(V) % N == 0:
    # Sort the list in ascending order (if needed)
    V.sort()

    increment = len(V) // N # the length of a subset

    for i in range(N):
        subset = V[i*increment: (i + 1)*increment]
        print(f"Subset {i + 1}:", subset)

        # Assign indices for each element in the subset with the specified pattern
        indices_subset = [(2*j-1,-1-2*i) for j in range(increment)]
        print(f"Indices for Subset {i + 1}:", indices_subset)

else:
    print(f"The length of V ({len(V)}) is not a multiple of {N=}. Cannot split into subsets.")
```

Output:

```
Subset 1: [3, 4, 5, 6]
Indices for Subset 1: [(-1, -1), (1, -1), (3, -1), (5, -1)]
Subset 2: [10, 11, 12, 13]
Indices for Subset 2: [(-1, -3), (1, -3), (3, -3), (5, -3)]
Subset 3: [17, 18, 19, 20]
Indices for Subset 3: [(-1, -5), (1, -5), (3, -5), (5, -5)]
```